# ArgumentError in LookController#at

Tags: ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu

I run RoR 3.2.0.rc1,  Ruby 1.9.2 and i work one Ubuntu 11.10

There is a name of error => ArgumentError in LookController#at

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

> ```
> Rails.root: /home/rene/ruby_dev/ch05/txt2fields
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>
> app/controllers/look_controller.rb:3:in 'text1'
> app/controllers/look_controller.rb:10:in 'at'
> ```

Request

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"5lxmVZMjEw4ifKaZHgevnr8hnsIyk+wD0WmZC71KMbc=",
 "text1"=>"René",
 "text2"=>"63",
 "method"=>"post"}
```

look_controller.rb

```
class LookController < ApplicationController

     def text1(string)
     end

     def trxt2(string)
     end

     def at
            @data = params[text1]
            @age = params[text2]            
     end

     def input
     end

end
```

imput.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UFT-8"/>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"; charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <!-- ... autres mentions de l'ent&ecirc;te de fichier ... -->
</head>

<html>
     <head>
            <title>Projet 3textfields, fichier input.rhtml</title>
     </head>
     <body>
            <h1>Les champs de saisie (champs de texte) : Exercice # 3</h1>
            <br>
            Cette application Ruby on Rails lit du texte saisi.
            <br>
            <br>
            Elle transmet la variable au modele.
            <br>
            <%= form_tag :action => 'at', :method => :post%>
            <br>
            Votre nom.
            <br>
            <%= text_field_tag "text1",  nil, :size => 30%>
            <br>
            Votre age.
            <br>
            <%= text_field_tag  "text2",  nil, :size => 30%>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit"/>
            <%=form_tag %>
     </body>
</html>
```

at.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"; charset="utf8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <!-- ... autres mentions de l'ent&ecirc;te de fichier ... -->
</head>

<html>
     <head>
            <title>Les champs de saisie : Exercice #2</title>
     </head>
     <body>
            <h1>Les champs de saisie ( Exercice #2  at.html )</h1>
            <br>
            <br>
            Vous vous appelez : <%= @data %>.
            <br>
            Vous avez : <%= @age %> ans.
            <br>            
            <br>
     </body>
</html>
```

i have error when a put a french accent one modèle in input.html

That is my problem ???

Comment: Oh, odd. I don't think that should be happening. Might be a bug... But, I'm probably wrong; I don't fancy RoR that much. Did you try Sinatra? :D

Answer (score 0):

The `at` method is calling `text1` and `text2` without any arguments, just like the error message says--they're both defined as taking a single argument. Pass an argument.

From the params it seems more like you actually want to retrieve request parameters:

```
def at
  @data = params[:text1]
  @age = params[:text2]
end
```

But hard to say, because you don't describe what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I just pass the answer at a question
in english : i ask What is your name ? the answer is René
2e question is What is your age?  Respond is 63

Comment: @René Okay. Doesn't change anything.

Comment: why accent é past in the answer i give you and don't past in a program ????  That is a question a make on the forum

Comment: thank you it's work.
I do resolve a franch accents in the program  wrhiting in HTML now

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `params[:text1]` and `params[:text2]` instead. When you omit the colon, it's using your `def text1(string)` method instead (And if this is your actual code, you might not even need the `text1` and `text2` methods).

```
@data = params[:text1]
@age = params[:text2]
```

Also, make sure your html files are named `input.html.erb` and `at.html.erb`, otherwise I don't think you'll see the actual contents of `@data` and `@age` properly.

Comment: I put .erb at end of the file inpur.html and at.html.
I have the same error